# Undefined control sequence \printbibliography bib file not right

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to compile my document but i keep getting undefined control sequence at \printbibliograpy and i think it has something to do with my bib file. Can someone help me identify what is wrong

```
@misc{noauthor_list_2021,
    title = {List of numeral systems},
    copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_numeral_systems&oldid=1025510791},
    abstract = {This is a list of numeral systems, that is, writing systems for expressing numbers.},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2021-06-01},
    journal = {Wikipedia},
    month = may,
    year = {2021},
    note = {Page Version ID: 1025510791},
}
```

This is my bibliography settings in my preamble.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chicago-authordate,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\input{settings}
\begin{document}
\input{chapters/frontpage}
\clearpage
\begin{abstract}
    Resume på Dansk.
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\input{chapters/indledning}
\input{chapters/problemformulering}
\input{chapters/besvarelse}
\input{chapters/metoder}
\input{chapters/konklusion}
\printbibliograpy
\section{Bilag}
\appendix
\input{chapters/appendix.tex}
\end{document}
```

And this is the error i get.

> Undefined control sequence. [\printbibliograpy]

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example so we can see what exactly you're doing, what class and packages you are using. Sounds to be like you forgot to load the `biblatex` package.

Comment: why do you think this bib entry is the problem? Do you get the error too, if you copy this entry in a small bib, and then try to use it in a small test document?

Comment: In a simple setup I cannot reproduce any issues with the shown entry (https://gist.github.com/moewew/5d06ccadabffbdac8dcadac22cf609df). Please make sure that the entry shown in the question is actually the culprit and please post a full example document that shows how you generate the bibliography in your document and that reproduces the issue (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: I updated the original question

Comment: There's a typo in your code: Do please change `\printbibliograpy` to `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the mistake. Wow. Sorry for bothering, i thought my bib file was messed up. English is not my first language so i must have over seen the spelling mistake

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE reproduces the issue. The problem occurs when a `note` field is present.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{vazques-de-parga}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The cause of the issue is that `biblatex-chicago` uses `xstring` commands, but the package is not loaded (`biblatex` used to load it, but no longer does so).

The solution is to load `biblatex-chicago` styles via the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago`, which loads `xstring` and sets up a few other things as well (language mapping, the proper style options). Unless you know what you are doing and have a good reason to do so, you should never load `biblatex-chicago` styles directly with `\usepackage{biblatex}`, you should always use `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}`.

The following compiles fine. Note that the style is given without the `style=` option name and without the `chicago-`prefix.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{vazques-de-parga}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. It also helps to replace `\printbibliograpy` with `\printbibliography`, doesn't it? :-)